# Defining a couple of functions, having trouble getting sheet names due to bound method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Learning python by doing.

Code:

```
import re, openpyxl, os
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def open_xl_file():
    loc = input("Please enter path of the file:")
    os.chdir(loc)
    file = input("Filename:")
    return openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

def sheet_select():
    wb = open_xl_file()
    print(wb.get_sheet_names)
    y = input("Which sheet?\n")
    return wb.get_sheet_by_name(y)
```

I get the output on `print(wb.get_sheet_names)` as:

`<bound method Workbook.get_sheet_names of <openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook object at 0x0000000004E3F2E8>>`

Trying to figure out where I messed up. I have tried including the wb in the first function and returning it.

Comment: Should be `print(wb.get_sheet_names())` ...

Comment: missing parenthesis `print(wb.get_sheet_names())` ?

Comment: Thanks!! That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several people have mentioned in the comments, you should be doing `print(wb.get_sheet_names())` not `print(wb.get_sheet_names)`.